# ECS can't make sense of memory reservation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

My ecs ec2 instance is getting killed because of memory.

I see the following charts and don't have idea what's going on..

MemoryUtilization shows I'm using less than 40% memory.. why is my instances getting killed?

Why MemoryReservation is only at 25%?
I have 2gig instance (t2.small) and I set soft limit to 512mb, I guess that's 25%..
So is my task getting killed if it goes over 25%?

[image]

Edit

- Task definitions

I increased memoryReservation from 512mb to 1024mb

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::244842952809:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/littlehome-web",
          "awslogs-region": "ap-northeast-2",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        },
        {
          "hostPort": 443,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 443
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": {
        "capabilities": null,
        "sharedMemorySize": null,
        "tmpfs": null,
        "devices": null,
        "maxSwap": 8192,
        "swappiness": 60,
        "initProcessEnabled": null
      },
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "repositoryCredentials": {
        "credentialsParameter": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-northeast-2:244842952809:secret:littlehome/dockerhub_secret-vsXHjb"
      },
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": 1024,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "docker.io/littlehome/littlehome",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "littlehome-web"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": null,
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::244842952809:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-2:244842952809:task-definition/littlehome-web:11",
  "family": "littlehome-web",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.private-registry-authentication.secretsmanager"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.21"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "networkMode": null,
  "cpu": null,
  "revision": 11,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

- ECS service settings

I run two or more EC2 instances.

- launch type: EC2
- service type: DAEMON
- number of tasks: automatic
- minimum healthy percent: 50

- Load balancer's target group health check settings

[image]

- scaling policy

[image]

- Error log I think is critical

From /var/log/messages

```
Oct 16 03:49:41 ip-172-31-20-96 amazon-ssm-agent: 2020-10-16 03:49:41 INFO [HealthCheck] HealthCheck reporting agent health.
Oct 16 03:50:36 ip-172-31-20-96 dhclient[3561]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 109600ms.
Oct 16 03:51:31 ip-172-31-20-96 containerd: time="2020-10-16T03:51:31.670433783Z" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=e72a206c96e3a300a24f3ffe97c889ea83b9a32469bde021b96b503f2fcd044c
Oct 16 03:51:31 ip-172-31-20-96 dockerd: time="2020-10-16T03:51:31.681898014Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Oct 16 03:51:31 ip-172-31-20-96 kernel: veth54fda6e: renamed from eth0
Oct 16 03:51:31 ip-172-31-20-96 kernel: docker0: port 1(vetha672ca6) entered disabled state
Oct 16 03:51:31 ip-172-31-20-96 kernel: docker0: port 1(vetha672ca6) entered disabled state
Oct 16 03:51:31 ip-172-31-20-96 kernel: device vetha672ca6 left promiscuous mode
Oct 16 03:51:31 ip-172-31-20-96 kernel: docker0: port 1(vetha672ca6) entered disabled state
Oct 16 03:51:42 ip-172-31-20-96 kernel: docker0: port 1(vethbb18961) entered blocking state
Oct 16 03:51:42 ip-172-31-20-96 kernel: docker0: port 1(vethbb18961) entered disabled state
Oct 16 03:51:42 ip-172-31-20-96 kernel: device vethbb18961 entered promiscuous mode
Oct 16 03:51:42 ip-172-31-20-96 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethbb18961: link is not ready
Oct 16 03:51:42 ip-172-31-20-96 containerd: time="2020-10-16T03:51:42.653192466Z" level=info msg="shim containerd-shim started" address=/containerd-shim/215fd03db701ddcb24f78c1107110f46e6321610c6c8883f87fc5369d83bf52c.sock debug=false pid=19760
Oct 16 03:51:42 ip-172-31-20-96 kernel: eth0: renamed from veth7926a05
Oct 16 03:51:42 ip-172-31-20-96 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethbb18961: link becomes ready
```

I read "shim reaped" could be caused by memory issue here (https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/2202)
And followed the instruction to disable `transparent hugepages.`

And I see they are disabled

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-20-96 ~]$ cat  /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always madvise [never]
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-20-96 ~]$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
always defer defer+madvise madvise [never]
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-20-96 ~]$
```

- health metrics

After I increased memory reservation from 512mb to 1024mb, the graph shows the change..

[image]

Comment: Is the ECS Task being killed, or the EC2 instance? Your question isn't entirely clear on that.

Comment: increasing ur soft limit to 1gb should help

Comment: The docker container is getting killed and restarted .. so yeah task is getting killed @MarkB

Comment: why increasing soft limit help? @DeepakSinghal

Comment: Your task is not being allowed to use any more memory on the EC2 instance it is deployed on. It is maxing out at 25% of the hosts's memory, and then probably experiencing performance issues once it can't obtain any more memory, after which ECS kills it due to health checks failing or something. Or maybe the process running in the Docker container simply errors out and exits. You should be able to determine from the ECS service and tasks logs, and from your ECS service health check settings, why it is exiting or being killed.

Comment: Include your task definition, ECS service settings, load balancer target group health check settings, auto-scaling settings, and any other relevant information in your question if you want an exact answer.

Comment: @MarkB I added the info ..

Comment: @MarkB it seems after increasing the soft memory limit, I am not seeing any more `shim reaped` in the logs..  Which I don't understand why..

Comment: @MarkB Can you explain why increasing soft limit fixes my issue? Cause I thought soft limit just plays a role when placing a task in a host..